# Error: Expected Type Parameter, Found Closure

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have the following [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=95a633530905a396580775d15dbd6971):

```
struct Helper<F1: Fn()> {
    f: F1,
}

struct User<F2: Fn()> {
    h: Helper<F2>,
}

fn new_user<F3: Fn()>() -> User<F3> {
    User {
        // error: expected type parameter, found closure
        h: Helper { f: || {} },
    }
}

fn main(){}
```

So `User` needs a `Helper<F1>` with the type of F1 being specified by `User`, in this case by the closure in `new_user`.

This code fails compile with the error `expected type parameter, found closure` in `new_user`. As far as I have understood (see for instance [this link](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51154)), this is because the bound of type parameter `F3` on `new_user` is specified by the caller (or signature maybe?), and so although the closure implements the `Fn()` trait, it won't be able to restrict the type parameter F3 to match the type of the closure. Instead, it is expected that `new_user` should work with any given `F3`, which it clearly won't.

So my question is: how do I fix this? Is there any way of expressing that I want `new_user` to return a `User` with `F2` set to the type of the closure?

I tried to use a type inference placeholder:

```
// error: the type placeholder `_` is not allowed within types on item signatures
fn new_user() -> User<_> {
    User {
        h: Helper { f: || {} },
    }
}
```

I could use Box, but this requires modifying `Helper`, which isn't ideal in my practical case:

```
struct Helper {
    f: Box<dyn Fn()>,
}

struct User {
    h: Helper,
}

fn new_user() -> User {
    User {
        h: Helper { f: Box::new(|| {}) },
    }
}

fn main(){}
```

I'm also experimenting a bit with replacing `Fn()` with a custom trait, which I can implement for `User` specifically, but so far it's been clunky.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr;** You probably want this:

```
fn new_user() -> User<impl Fn()> {
    User {
        h: Helper { f: || {} },
    }
}
```

**More details:** Let's look into this:

```
fn new_user<F3: Fn()>() -> User<F3> {
    User {
        // error: expected type parameter, found closure
        h: Helper { f: || {} },
    }
}
```

This states that `new_user` "accepts" *anything* satisfying `Fn()`, but the caller must specify it when calling `new_user`. However, to successfully type-check, the supplied type would have to be the same as the one used within the body of `new_user`, (which is the type of `|| {}`). However, closures have anonymous types, so the caller of `new_user` cannot know this type, since it cannot look into the implementation of `new_user` too find out what to supply for `F3`.

As said, what you want is that `new_user` returns a `User<SomeConcreteType>` where `SomeConcreteType` satisfies `F3`. The caller does not need to - in fact it should not even - specify `SomeConcreteType`, because it is inferred within `new_user`. You can do this as follows:

```
fn new_user() -> User<impl Fn()> {
    User {
        h: Helper { f: || {} },
    }
}
```

This way, you specify that `new_user` can be called without any arguments and it returns a `User` with some concrete type satisfying `Fn()`.