# Generate and store closure in struct initialisation

Tags: rust

Is it possible to generate and store a closure in  a struct: currently getting the error mismatched types

```rust
pub struct MM<F>
where
    F: Fn(&f64, &f64) -> f64,
{
    pub n: f64, //
    pub y: f64, //
    p: f64,     // the p parameter associated with prior probability
    f: F,       // this must only take two arguments
}

impl<F> MM<F>
where
    F: Fn(&f64, &f64) -> f64,
{
    pub fn new(l: f64, prior: f64) -> Self {
        let func = |a: &f64, b: &f64| -> f64 { b.powf(prior) * a };
        MM {
            n: l,
            y: l,
            p: prior,
            f: func,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Desn't this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52934680/1173020?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some adjustments to the code you've posted. Mainly I've changed the return type of `new` ([see explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54118880/124257) as to why this is necessary). I've also changed `CFMM` to `MM` in the struct creation of `new`, it seems like that was a typo.

Short version for the impatient: you can't return `Self` from `new` and put a closure in it. The compiler will tell you that

> every closure has a distinct type and so could not always match the **caller-chosen type** of parameter `F`

if you attempt to do this. The key element here is "caller-chosen". Rust cannot guarantee that the closure we're constructing in `new` will match whatever the caller decides `F` should be. As soon as you make `new` decide explicitly what it will return `impl Fn(...)` it works.

There's some more explanation available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73205224/124257) as well.

```rust
pub struct MM<F: Fn(&f64, &f64) -> f64> {
    pub n: f64,
    pub y: f64,
    pub p: f64,     // the p parameter associated with prior probability
    pub f: F,       // this must only take two arguments
}

pub fn new_mm(l: f64, prior: f64) -> MM<impl Fn(&f64, &f64) -> f64> {
    let func = move |a: &f64, b: &f64| -> f64 { b.powf(prior) * a };
    MM {
        n: l,
        y: l,
        p: prior,
        f: func,
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: f64 = 1.0;
    let b: f64 = 0.9;
    let p  = new_mm(a, b);
    println!("{}", (p.f)(&1.0, &2.0));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=15cd874a1d106655b08979b33f9682a7)

Comment: Thanks: this removes the error in the struct itself but it doesn't seem possible to actually initialiase using ::new in main as it doesn't seem to either find the type parameters, or like them not being declared. 
```rust
fn main() {
    let a = 1.0;
    let b = 0.9;
    let p:CFMM<F>  =
    {CFMM::new(a, b)};
}
```

Comment: You're right. My Rust-foo is not strong enough to solve this while keeping `new` as an associated function to the struct itself. I think this may be a chicken-egg problem, so I'm not 100% sure it is solvable. In any case, if you move `new` out of the struct it works fine :) I've updated the answer to reflect that.